# Get dynamic multidimensional arrray jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am using WordPress to localize a multidimensional array as seen here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8851/9065

My array reads as:

```
var h5ap = [];
h5ap = {"album_id_982":{"albumdesc":"","tracks":2,"audio":[],"988":{"audio":{"title":"Same Old Story","artist":"Extendd Plugins","cover":false}},"989":{"audio":{"title":"Aliens","artist":"Extendd Plugins","cover":false}}}};
```

Normally accessing it with jQuery you would do this:

```
$(h5ap.album_id_982)
```

But the XX in `album_id_XX` number is dynamic and changes as per post ID. And I can't figure out how to access it.

Comment: bracket notation. This has nothing to do with wordpress or jQuery, and it's an object not a multi-dimensional array array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK since an javascript object and array are the same, you could access the elements in your oject the same way you access an array.

I mean, if you do:

```
h5ap['album_id_xxx']['xxx'];
```

it should return the element you want... see in this jsfiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/rdenadai/KjMcw/5/

cheers

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I didn't think of that. Guess I was staring at it for a bit to long.

Comment: thats ok... i must correct one thing in my accept answer... you can access objects using the array notation as i answer, but fundamentally they are not the same as a state above.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying my JS variable to read as folows:

```
var h5ap = [];
h5ap['swfpath'] = 'http://.../swf';

h5ap['982'] = [];
h5ap['982']['tracks'] = '2';
h5ap['982']['audio'] = [
{
title: 'Same Old Story',
artist: 'Extendd Plugins',
},{
title: 'Aliens',
artist: 'Extendd Plugins',
},
```

];

Where I can now find the dynamic ID of the `h5ap` variable and access all sub arrays with ease.